# Dynamic Formula Creation

Tags: excel, vba

In Sheet1
i have one stagnant Column suppose Column "A"
which gets copied again and again in next empty column in same Sheet

Like 1st it gets copied in  Column "B" then find next empty column & copy data in Column "C"

--> Here my question is

I want to create formula in Sheet 2 in Column "A"
where it make Formula with next filled column in Sheet1

Like

1. 1st it makes calculation: `Sheet1!A1/Sheet1!B1`

   After few min
2. it make formula in same Column "A" oF Sheet2: `Sheet1!A1/Sheet1!C1`

   After few min

so on

```
Sub GoToNextCol()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim NextCol As Long
    NextCol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheet1.Cells(1, NextCol)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

In Sheet2 cell A1

```
sheet2.range("a1").formula="=Sheet1!A1/Sheet1!" & cells(1,nextcol).address(0,0)
```

Comment: thank you so much ..you are on my favorites list  ----

Comment: what if i have to create this Formula @SJR --> =IF(Sheet1!B1>Sheet1!C1, IF(Sheet1!B1>Sheet1!D1, 2, 1),IF(Sheet1!B1<Sheet1!C1, IF(Sheet1!B1<Sheet1!D1, -2, -1),0))   & Further Column gets incremental like C & D changes to E & F ---- Then E & F Changes to G & H like this ....

Comment: It's the same principle. `cells(1,nextcol).address(0,0)` resolves to C1 when `nextcol=3` and so on.